# How build a following table in MYsql

Tags: android, mysql

I am designing an  android app. I would like build the following table.

**Table name :** EXE1

```
nAME  m1 m2 m3 m4
P1    23 34 35 36
P2    09 89 34 35
P3    89 12 13 14
```

As in the above table I want to enter only integers  based up on date  nd where `m1`, `m2`, `m3` `m4` are different coloumns and `p1`,`p2`,`p3` are different rows which are constant.

I have tried by using `AUTOINCREMENT` but I could not stop it after `p3` and I was able enter irrespective of `m1`,`m2`,`m3`  where I want enter different data.

Please help me how to create it.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps there's something I don't understand?  What's wrong with:

```
CREATE TABLE EXE1 (
  nAME VARCHAR(15),
  m1   INT,
  m2   INT,
  m3   INT,
  m4   INT
);

INSERT INTO EXE1
  (nAME, m1, m2, m3, m4)
VALUES
  ('P1', 23, 34, 35, 36),
  ('P2', 09, 89, 34, 35),
  ('P3', 89, 12, 13, 14)
;
```

Comment: Actually I want P1,P2,P3 to be primary when I give             INSERT INTO EXE1
  (nAME, m1, m2, m3, m4)
VALUES
  ('Null', 23, 34, 35, 36)                                                   It should enter into table like 'P1': 23, 34, 35, 36 And when I select to enter It should enter into 'P2': 23, 34, 35, 36 and that also only once I dont want multiple values P1 like 'P1': 23, 34, 35, 36  'P1': 34, 35, 38, 39

Comment: @raja: Why not just use an incrementing integer and prepend the `'P'` on data retrieval?

Comment: For your easy understanding let take an example of 6 students (p1,p2,p3) and has got a marks for 4 different subjects (m1,m2,m3,m4) Hence I will enter marks of a subject m1 for all the students and the students are constant like 6. may I can repeat the student based upon time but it will be later on.

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL you can't use a command to directly control a table's number of rows. And it's really not a good practice to build a table with a string field as PK.
An approximation of what you want is to create a table with an integer auto_increment id and add a unique index field,

```
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `exe1` (
  `id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `exe_name` VARCHAR(15) NULL ,
  `m1` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 ,
  `m2` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 ,
  `m3` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 ,
  `m4` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) ,
  UNIQUE INDEX `exe_name_UNIQUE` (`exe_name` ASC) )
ENGINE = InnoDB;

DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `exe_insert` BEFORE INSERT ON exe1
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
  SET NEW.exe_name = IFNULL(NEW.exe_name, CONCAT("P",NEW.id));
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

A simple trigger called `exe_insert` would generate new row's `exe_name`, if one's not given.

---

From MySQL doc,

> A UNIQUE index creates a constraint such that all values in the index
>   must be distinct. An error occurs if you try to add a new row with a
>   key value that matches an existing row. For all engines, a UNIQUE
>   index permits multiple NULL values for columns that can contain NULL.
>   [[...]](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-index.html)

And also it's worthy a few reading on [triggers](http://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-create-mysql-triggers/).